Can I write off a car that will be used for reverse engineering and product testing?
I am an electrical engineering consultant (self employed) helping a client develop an accessory for Electric Vehicles. I need to have an EV to reverse engineer some of the protocols, and to test prototypes on. It would be used for some amount of business related driving, but it would also be used for normal stuff (getting kids to school, groceries, etc.) and I'd want to keep it when the product development is complete (though there may be future products that use it as well).
For development so far I've used borrowed cars and rentals, which isn't ideal.
Since my primary business reason for buying the car would not be driving it, but testing on it, does that change anything for writing it off? For example, if I was buying some other machine to reverse engineer, car stuff wouldn't even be relevant. But I realize I am muddying things by driving it.
If I can write it off, how much can I write off? It sounds like cars have to be written off over the course of several years. Does that apply here as well? (If I had my way, I'd love to write the whole thing off this year.)
I'm not looking for specifics, just trying to see if I can justify the purchase, and whether I can reasonably use some of the money I have set aside for taxes to cover the cost. Thanks!
Update to clarify some things: First, perhaps "reverse engineering" has a negative connotation, but what I am doing isn't illegal, or even frowned upon. It's completely reasonable in this context. Let me give an example. Let's say I am designing a power adapter for a laptop (a reasonable thing for an engineer to do), but the manufacturer chose not to publish the specifications of their adapter. So I buy a laptop and an adapter, I measure the size of the connector and the voltage, then I make my own adapter using that information and plug it into the laptop to make sure it works. This cannot be done reasonably without buying the laptop and adapter. So it seems that buying those things would be a business expense (in my mind at least. I'm not sure if tax law agrees, which is why I am here).
That's what I am doing, but with an EV.
So to apply that to my actual situation. I am making an accessory for an EV that can not reasonably be made without having access to an EV. If I buy the car and never drive it, but use it only for taking measurements from and for testing my product on, it sounds like that would be something I could write off, is that correct? In that case, since it is not actually being used to move people or goods, it seems (to me at least, see disclaimer above) that maybe the normal car rules wouldn't apply, as I'm not, in this case, using it as a car, but just a piece of machinery to be interfaced with. To be clear, the primary impetus for buying the car is not to drive it at all.
Now, to continue my earlier example, if I legitimately need to buy this laptop to develop the adapter, then when I am done with development, what happens? Do I need to leave it untouched or throw it away lest I risk the wrath of the IRS? In the case or the laptop or the EV, it seems that not using it after development was done would be pointlessly wasteful.
Perhaps the answer here is that I can't write it off because that's the sort of thing that people would be too likely to abuse (like how, for the same reason, I can't write off the lost income from clients who don't pay, if I understand correctly). Fair enough, that's what I asked this question to learn. I am not trying to do anything nefarious here (if I were, I wouldn't be asking, would I?), but I do want to take advantage of opportunities to reduce my taxes if they legally, reasonably available.

IF you elect accrual accounting instead of cash, so you report income (and pay tax on it) for the year you earn it (do the work or deliver material) and a customer subsequently fails to pay the bill for that work or material, you can deduct that bad debt (and approximately get back the tax previously paid on the 'imaginary' income). But accrual-basis requires good records and very few individuals use it. (And changing accounting basis after your first filing year requires permission from the IRS, to prevent you manipulating the system.)


I need to have an EV to reverse engineer some of the protocols, and to
test prototypes on. It would be used for some amount of business
related driving, but it would also be used for normal stuff (getting
kids to school, groceries, etc.) and I'd want to keep it when the
product development is complete (though there may be future products
that use it as well).

When a business is planning on claiming an item as a business expense, but also has a plan for personal use of the item, their accountant and their tax advisor get nervous. This is true when the item is low cost, but they get really concerned when the item costs tens of thousands of dollars.
Getting this wrong can cost you a lot in taxes and penalties. If the IRS audits you, and determines that the EV was improperly claimed as a business expense, it can get very expensive.

For development so far I've used borrowed cars and rentals, which
isn't ideal.

I assume you told the owners what you were doing, but did you tell the rental company? They might have had concerns.

For example, if I was buying some other machine to reverse engineer,
car stuff wouldn't even be relevant. But I realize I am muddying
things by driving it.

People have been looking for this type of loophole. The ability to treat a non-business expense as a business expense seems like a good way to save money. People buy a business laptop, but then they use it for non-business things.

If I can write it off, how much can I write off? It sounds like cars
have to be written off over the course of several years. Does that
apply here as well? (If I had my way, I'd love to write the whole
thing off this year.)

Talk to your tax advisor. With this much money at risk you need a tax advisor.

I understand it may be ambiguous (or maybe not), which is why I am asking for help. Please know my question comes from sincerely wanting more information, and because I think the situation is a little bit unusual. Regarding the use of borrowed and rental cars: the measurements I made were entirely harmless and non-intrusive. I did not disassemble anything nor was their any risk of damage. I only measured things that could be accessed by any normal user of the car. Finally, and forgive me but, if I had a tax advisor, I wouldn't be posting this question here.

@notloc 'Finally, and forgive me but, if I had a tax advisor, I wouldn't be posting this question here' That's why the last line in this answer is so important. If you are contemplating buying an EV then the stakes are big enough that you absolutely need professional tax advice. If you make a mistake and the IRS comes after you, it's exculpatory to say "But I was relying on advice from a tax professional!". It's not exculpatory to say "But I asked some folks on the internet and they said it was ok!".

If you're contemplating having your business buy something as expensive as a car, particularly where you are doing unusual things with that car, it is time to have a conversation with a tax professional who can stand behind you if you are audited.
The immediate problem is that the IRS has a standard approach for cars that are used for both business and personal use.  You simply log the miles you use for business and you can deduct that fraction of the car.  But in your case, you'd not be driving the car for business purposes but you would be driving it for personal purposes.  So if you want to deduct anything, you'd be outside the realm of "normal" car expensing rules.  Hence the need for a tax professional.
A plausible scenario would be to have the business buy the car, do whatever testing you need to do, and then convert the car to 100% personal use by buying the car from the business at the fair market value of the car at the time (which may create a taxable gain if you buy the car from the business in a different tax year).  If you're expecting that it's going to take months or years to do whatever analysis you need to do, the difference in fair market value might be enough to be worth the hassle of trying to deduct the difference.  If you're expecting that it is going to take days or a weeks to do this analysis, it is unlikely that the fair market value of the car would change meaningfully so there would be no expense for the business to recognize.

FMV of a brand new car drops by about 10-15% the moment it leaves the dealership lot. Buying from yourself is a non-event, and I would tread really carefully trying to expense a significant amount for 2 weeks of tinkering with the car on a parking lot.

@littleadv - Hence the very first sentence to speak with a tax advisor.  But in general a business can buy an asset, use that asset, and then dispose of that asset by converting it to personal use.  If we're talking about a new car, rather than a used car, and the analysis takes a few days to do then you're probably going to have difficulty convincing the IRS that you're not just trying to get the business to be able to expense that initial depreciation for a personal vehicle.  If the car spends months being used 100% for business, that argument gets easier to make.

From what you're describing the primary use of the car would be for personal use. You can maintain a contemporary record of miles driven for business and prorate expenses accordingly.
It's not clear what you mean by "reverse engineer". Generally, expenses for illegal activity are not deductible.

To expand a little on your clarifications and comments:
It doesn't matter to me what you're doing and whether it is legal. I'm not a lawyer and can't form an educated opinion on the matter. What I do know that if you are doing something illegal - then you cannot take a business deduction for the expenses related to that. So talk to a lawyer about your business with that in mind.
As to deducting business expenses - if you buy a car that never drives and you use it solely for your business, then yes, you can claim it as a business asset. Such assets are usually not deducted as an single-purchase expense but rather depreciated over time. There are some additional rules that may change the general depreciation requirement, check with your tax advisor.
However, if you are driving the car, then you need to prorate business and personal use, and only deduct the portion attributable to the business use. So if the odometer changes between the purchase and the disposal of the car and you didn't only drive it for business needs - you'll have to prorate based on the actual driven miles.
It's even worse with laptops - you bought a laptop to measure it's voltage, and that's all you need for your business. But you then used the laptop for a personal use to check your email or whats not - you cannot deduct the laptop as a business expense. It's your personal laptop.
You're not the first to buy something "for business" and "only slightly use for myself".
As to your comment that you cannot deduct money you haven't been paid - you cannot deduct it because it's not an expense. You didn't lose anything since you never had it to begin with (if you're a cash based taxpayer). Had you had it, you'd pay tax on it. Since you never got it - there's no tax to pay. Why would you expect to double dip and also take a deduction?

I wouldn't buy the car if I didn't need it for developing this product. Personal use is not the reason for buying it, but ultimately it would see more personal use than business use. Maybe the distinction is immaterial? That's what I am asking to learn. I'm trying to be upfront and give all the information I think is relevant. Please see my clarifications above. Also, if I may, insinuating criminal intent from someone who comes to you for help, while in the same sentence admitting that you may not have understood the their meaning, might not be the best way to endear yourself to others.

@notloc my goal is not to endear, it's to provide information. What your intention is - is immaterial. What's material is your use. You said you'd be using it for your own personal use, so that's not a business property. The IRS does allow business use of a personal vehicle - as I said, you log business trips in your mileage log and you prorate the car use accordingly. The legality of your business is of no consequence to me, but it is to you. If you're convinced you're not breaking any laws - good for you, but in case you are you should know that it would also affect your deductions.

"I wouldn't buy the car if I didn't need it for developing this product." Maybe not this car. But you would buy a car. If not then you can not use this car for personal use and continue to do whatever you would have done for personal trips without it.

You're goal may not be to endear, but accursing me of illegal acts doesn't seem to conform to the very first item in the code of conduct for this side: "No matter where you engage on the network with your peers, we expect all users to treat one another with kindness and respect." Anyway, and again, I am asking because of my ignorance. Unless I'm misunderstanding, it seems there are contradictions in your reply. "The IRS does not allow business use of a personal vehicle" but "you can log business trips ... and prorate ... accordingly" so there is a way, in that case. Is there a way in my case?

I've expanded my answer given your clarifications. I have not accused you of anything. Feel free to ignore me, but please do not violate the exact provision you're quoting at me by defaming me and offending me in return for the help I'm giving you.

And yes, you're misunderstanding. You didn't quote what I said. Read it again, carefully.

I'm sorry, I felt your comment of "Generally, expenses for illegal activity are not deductible." was an implication that my work was illegal, if that is not how it was intended then I apologize. I'm not trying to escalate this further.

@DJClayworth I would not be buying a car at this time if not for this project. I have one already. So it sounds like if I keep both and use them separately, then I'd be okay?

@notloc no worries, but I do suggest to talk to an actual tax advisor. And yes, a lawyer. While you may think you're not breaking any laws, the reality of copyrights, trademarks, trade secrets, and patents, may be very different. Reverse engineering is a sensitive topic which may in fact be illegal in some jurisdictions.

Just to clarify, I'm unaware of any jurisdiction in which reverse engineering per se is illegal in the sense that there is an actual law against it. It's typically covered by contract law, and there are legal consequences for breaking contracts. It's these legal consequences that people typically mean by saying "it might be illegal".  In some jurisdictions the law actually goes the other way and says contracts forbidding reverse engineering are not enforceable. Building and selling something that is based on reverse engineering might run afoul of patent or trademark law.
